# Biggest set of binary strings where OR of any $j$ is reversible

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, computer-science, information-theory, classical-mechanics

For $\small{i,j}$, what is $\small{\max\kern-0.12em| \kern-0.02em \mathcal{C} \kern-0.02em|}$, $\small{\kern-0.05em\mathcal{C}\kern-0.05em}$ among sets of binary $\small{i}$-strings where $\small{(\kern-0.05em u \kern-0.1em \mapsto \kern-0.25em \vee_{s\in u}s)}$ is injective over $\small{\kern-0.05em u \kern-0.15em\subset \kern-0.15em \mathcal{C} \kern-0.17em: \kern-0.17em| \kern-0.05em u \kern-0.05em| \kern-0.2em\leq \kern-0.15em j}$?

Comment: Is there a systematic form for maximal $\small{\mathcal{C}}$ that gives an efficient scheme for identifying $\small{u}$ from $\small{\vee_{s\in u}s}$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a(i,j)$ be the desired maximum value.  The following properties are immediate:
\begin{align}
a(i,1) &= 2^i\\
a(i,j) &\ge i\\
a(i,j) &\ge a(i-1,j) + 1 \\
a(i,j) &\le a(i,j-1)
\end{align}

For $j\ge 2$, [Sperner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem) implies that $a(i,j)\le \binom{i}{\lfloor i/2 \rfloor}$.

Here are some values for small $i$ and $j$, obtained via integer linear programming:
\begin{matrix}
i\backslash j  &1     &2      &\ge 3\\
\hline
 1    &2     &1      &1\\
 2    &4     &2      &2\\
 3    &8     &3      &3\\
 4   &16     &4      &4\\
 5   &32     &5      &5\\
 6   &64     &7      &6\\
 7  &128     &9      &7\\
 8  &256    &12   &[8,12]\\
 9  &512 &\ge 15   &\ge 9\\
10 &1024 &\ge 16  &\ge 10
\end{matrix}

Comment: Rob, thanks for the answer, I haven't thought through this yet, but are these properties sufficient for the constraint in the original post?

Comment: These properties are necessary but not sufficient.